# How to make accordion to shrink when other tab is open

Tags: javascript, html, css

I`m trying to make my acordion to do what i want. Now it works just fine, but I want to make one tab to shrink while other is being opened. Basically I want to have open just one tab at the time. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
    <button class="accordion">Kontaktai</button>
  <div class="panel">

    <ul style="list-style-type:none; text-align: center; margin-left: -35px;">
      <p style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">Text</p>


  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Kaip mus rasti?</button>
  <div class="panel">
      <p style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">Text</p>

  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Apie mus</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.maxHeight){
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + 'px';
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
```

I hope you understood what I want from this code.

Comment: so you have to close the open tab when opening a new one; what's the question? And what's the point of this half/broken `<ul>` in your html-markup? And please avoid inline styles *(at least putting them manually into the html-markup)*. They'll just make your life harder. Use an external stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

well the code is recursive and redundant but it will work fine for removing active class from your elements, you can add up more operations as you need:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
 acc[i].onclick = function() {
   var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].className = acc[i].className.replace("active","");
   }
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.maxHeight){
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + 'px';
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
.active{
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
  <button class="accordion">Kontaktai</button>
  <div class="panel">

    <ul style="list-style-type:none; text-align: center; margin-left: -35px;">
      <p style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">Text</p>


  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Kaip mus rasti?</button>
  <div class="panel">
      <p style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">Text</p>

  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Apie mus</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".accordion").click(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
      $(this).next(".panel").toggle();
    }else{
      $(".accordion").removeClass("active");
      $(".panel").hide();
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $(this).next(".panel").toggle();
    }

});</script>
```

Please try this. It worked for me.

Comment: Since OP is not using jQuery but only vanilla JS, I think there’s a good chance they might want to keep it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery accordion plugin for this. It gives many advanced features. Hope [this](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) link will help you.